# Polishing a Character Controller collision detection to make it flush with surfaces

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, linear-algebra

I've been looking through the Source SDK and read through how it handles player collision with the space around it. Inspired by that, I've been writing a character controller that should have similar behavior.

I have code to control a Transform `transform` by computing its velocity `vecVelocity` and trying to move it along that vector. I represent the player by a capsule of radius `capsuleRadius` and sphere centers `capsuleStart, capsuleEnd`, but I haven't given it a proper collider as of yet

When trying to deal with collisions, I came up with the following function

```
void TryPlayerMove()
    {
        Vector3 transDirection;
        float transMagnitude;

        Vector3 translation;
        Vector3 currentMotion = Vector3.zero;
        int i, j, maxHits = 4; //Bump up to 4 times before giving up
        RaycastHit capsule;
        bool collision;

        Vector3[] collNormal = new Vector3[maxHits];
        float collDistance;


        //Find starting translation vector
        translation = vecVelocity * Time.deltaTime;

        //Store initial displacement
        Vector3 oldTranslation = translation;

        for (i = 0; i < maxHits; i++)
        {
            //Find translation vector magnitude and direction
            transDirection = translation.normalized;
            transMagnitude = translation.magnitude;

            //If we wouldn't move anyway, feel free to break the loop
            if (transMagnitude == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            //Shoot a capsule to desired endpoint
            collision = Physics.CapsuleCast(capsuleStart + currentMotion, capsuleEnd + currentMotion, capsuleRadius, transDirection, out capsule, transMagnitude);

            if (collision)
            {
                //If we hit something, hug it and take off what is left of translation in that direction
                collNormal[i] = capsule.normal.normalized;
                collDistance = capsule.distance;

                //currentMotion += transDirection * collDistance; //WHY DOESN'T THIS WORK???

                translation = ClipVector(translation*(1f-collDistance/transMagnitude), collNormal[i]);

                Debug.Log(transDirection.magnitude);

                //If we're going towards something we've hit before, stop moving so we don't go into weird corner loops
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if (Vector3.Dot(translation, collNormal[j]) < 0) 
                    {
                        translation = Vector3.zero;
                        break; 
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //Just move
                currentMotion += translation;
                break;
            }
        }
        

        //Translate the player character and take note of its velocity for future computation
        vecVelocity = currentMotion / Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(currentMotion, Space.World);
    }
```

and the clipping function just makes sure our vector is REALLY not pointing at the collider

```
Vector3 ClipVector(Vector3 inputVector, Vector3 normalVector)
    {
        float projection;
        Vector3 outputVector;

        //Determine how much to take out
        projection = Vector3.Dot(inputVector, normalVector);

        //Subtract the perpendicular component
        outputVector = inputVector - normalVector * projection;

        //Iterate once more just to make sure
        float adjust = Vector3.Dot(outputVector, normalVector);

        if (adjust < 0f)
        {
            outputVector -= normalVector * adjust;
        }

        return outputVector;
    }
```

This works fine as it is, and the controls respond quite as I would expect, but with a cosmetic fault: each time the player "collides" with something, it does so stopping at a different distance from the object, I've logged it and it fluctuates around 5-10 percent of the capsule's radius away from the player.

In the `TryPlayerMove()` function, there is a command that I would expect to make it hug the collider, it's commented and decorated with a note of desperation

`//currentMotion += transDirection * collDistance; //WHY DOESN'T THIS WORK???`

Whenever I uncomment this, the controller invariably goes through absolutely any collider it touches and completely messes up whatever motion it was supposed to have. I have no idea why this happens, though.

How could I implement a functionality for my player to hug the colliders it touches, seeing this doesn't seem to work at all?

Answer (score 1):

I found a hacky fix for it out of the blue. I have a `float deltaGround`I use to check for ground. I changed the command to

`currentMotion += transDirection * (collDistance-deltaGround/20f);`

but the 20 could have been any reasonably sized number. This makes it much more consistent but introduces some jitter in player motion when I try to ram myself against a wall. Still taking more suggestions.

I had tried `Mathf.Epsilon` but it didn't fix anything, by the way.